# cakephp delete button

Tags: cakephp

I want to make a delete button in CakePHP that delete selected records by an action in the specific controller, I want when user click deleted button the selected records delete then the same page reload then user see other records
my problem is when delete button go to delete action then the page go to delete view and I don't want this because the records are too much and I use pagination and I want the page back in the same page in pagination.
thanks guys

> this is my removeAll action

```
function removeAll() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->FormData->setJoin();
        if(empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $data;
            $this->render('remove');
        } else {
            foreach($this->data as $id => $item) 
                if($item == 1) $delete[]=$id;
                foreach($delete as $deleted) {
                    if(($data = $this->FormData->findById($id)) && ('Approved' !=$data['FormData']['status'] || $this->Authake->isAdmin())){
                        if($this->Values->deleteAll(array("          {$this->Values->alias}.formdata_id"=>$deleted)))
                        if($this->FormData->delete($deleted));
                    } else {
                        $this->redirect('authake/user/denied');
                    }
        }
                $this->set('success' ,true);
                $id=$this->data['id'];

                $this->redirect('/form/list'.$id);

    }
```

when page come to this action then its view(imean removeall.ctp)must loaded but idont want this.
i want back to the same page

Comment: You really need to show the code you have. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: Kindly provide some code so that someone can help you.

Comment: This..is an absurdly unreadable question. You have _one_ period in the entire question? That has to be a world record of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current page here:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => ('{:page}')
      )); 
?>
```

This is part of the solution.

Save this variable and in your controller, inside Paginator put that variable when you use a new request. Maybe 'current_page' or something like that inside Paginator. Try with documentation. Google is your friend. :)